# FIle download stops when file size is greater than 3mb. Receiving Failed - Network error message .NET MVC

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to download some files saved on my server's file system. I'm building the URL and accessing it. It works fine on small size files but when downloading 3mb or up, the downloads stop and I receive 'Failed - Network error'. I cannot reproduce this locally though. I'm guessing that this could be a configuration issue on my application.

I have a web application that access my API. The API returns the file as a File Result.

This is the code I'm using:

```
 var filePath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/DisputeFiles/" + pdi + "/"), fi);
 var isValidFile = new DisputeRepository().IsValidDisputeAttachment(Guid.Parse(udi), Guid.Parse(pdi), fi);
 if (isValidFile && !FileNotAvailable(filePath))
     return File(filePath, MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(fi), fi);
```

The APP and API are both on HTTPS protocol (Not sure if this may cause it by I doubt it).

I have added this on my API's webconfig under system.web

```
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2" maxRequestLength="1048576"/>
```

and this is under system.webserver

```
<security>
  <requestFiltering>
    <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="1073741824" />
  </requestFiltering>
</security>
```

This is also present on my APP's webconfig since uploading is one of the function on my application.

Here is a sample image on what I was encountering.

[image]

The download starts and downloads bits of it initially then slowly drops until a sudden stop.

Hoping you guys have an idea on how to fix this. Any help will be much appreciated. Thank you.

Edit:

Additional info about my server.

```
ec2 instance t2 micro
MS Server 2016
IIS Version 10.0.14393.0
```

Comment: Are you sure the error message is wrong? Perhaps there *is* a network error? Or a faulty proxy/cache used by whoever reported this?

Comment: Someone from a different country reported this and I can replicate it. My server's seems fine as well. Can you tell me more about "faulty proxy/cache" this?